# Animation on scroll (only animate once)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an "active" tag that is set to be added to elements with the class "reveal" when they are in the viewport. But after I scroll down the class "active" is now removed. How do I make it so that when "active" is first applied it does not get removed again. Below is the JavaScript that adds the "active" class.

```js
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");

  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 20;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    } 
    else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
```

Comment: remove `else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }`

Comment: Why do you have `.remove("active")` if you don't want to remove the `active` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using if else condition which is not required here. Just using a if block inside loop will do the work. Please see below code:

```js
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");

  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 20;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    }
    /*
    Not needed
    else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    */

  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
```

I have commented else block so it is not executed.